# What becomes of an array element when it turns null in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays

So I'm writing a big AJAX control class, and I've run into a bit of a curiosity.

Let's for the sake of conversation say I add all of the elements of my page into an array on initialization.

When someone executes an AJAX enabled link, the subsequent methods replace specified sections of content with what was received from the AJAX call.

Suppose however, that when this AJAX call completes, and replaces nodes inside of a section of content, the nodes that were previously stored in the array are now null or undefined ( or whatever signifies dead... ( not a javascript guru, clearly )).

What happens when I loop through all of the nodes in my array again? Are these elements no longer present? Or are they still consuming space at their old index, but now just inaccessible?

This seems like a bit of a silly question but effectively I'm just trying to see if there is any detection and trash collection that occurs on 'dead' elements in a javascript array.

Thanks and Cheers.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the code. Replacing nodes in the DOM and replacing elements of an array are two different things.

Comment: Apologies; but to elaborate in the simplest of ways, hopefully without having to write a bit of code to demo this, the array consists entirely of 'modified' DOM nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a DOM node in an array in javascript and then remove it from the DOM (e.g. after your ajax call), the node will continue to exist in the array, and continue to take  up space.  You can then add it to the DOM again later if you wish.

If you do not add it to the DOM again, and instead set the item in the array to some other value such as null or undefined, assuming that there are no remaining references to that element, it will be garbage collected and no longer take up space.

It's worth bearing in mind that there is a difference between a javascript array and a `NodeList` or a `HTMLCollection`.  You can get a node list by calling some DOM methods such as `document.getElementsByTagName`.  NodeLists look a bit like arrays, but remain 'live', so if a node is removed from the DOM it will be removed from the `NodeList` too.

Comment: Two simple questions; first, if I were to set the element to null in the array, would it still remain as a 'null' element in the array? I.E. would I have to remove the index from the array? And second; and more frivolous - do you have any good examples of an implementation of a NodeList?

Comment: if you explicitly set an element to null or undefined it stays as a null or undefined in the array (although you shouldn't worry about this taking up much space).  To remove an element from an array you need to use the `splice` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsplice), or if the elements are at the start you can use `shift` or at the end `pop`.  You can also truncate an array by just assigning a smaller value to its `.length` property.

Comment: Basically, you only need to worry about `NodeList`s if you use one of the methods that returns one.  If you do that and you're not expecting the return collection to be 'live' it can be quite surprising.  You can worry about it if you are using `getElementsByTagName`, or the `.children` or `.childNodes` attributes.  I believe that the xpath methods can also optionally return live iterators. Sometimes having a live collection is what you want, other than that arrays are fine and a bit more convenient.

Comment: I believe what I ultimately want to do is use an empty NodeList ( tied to the document? ) and populate specific elements - but those elements would have stringent requirements for particular attributes; so I feel that creating my own NodeList is a must, but perhaps for the time being I'll just splice out null elements as I go. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If a DOM element is removed from the active page, references to it are not turned to null. The elements will be stored in memory until such time as no more references to the elements exist and the garbage collector has collected the garbage.

What this means is that you'd be able to use an array of DOM nodes to restore those nodes should they be removed from their parent elements.